# How to play lottie animation half?

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

Help me!
I want mute and unmute button with Lottie animation. But this [mute.json](https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/animated-icons/icons/no-sound/no-sound.json) json animation have both.
So I need one click play Lottie half animation like this.
When clicked [image: Mute] and [image: Unmute]

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this)
      ..value = 0.5
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // Rebuild the widget at each frame to update the "progress" label.
        });
      }); 
  }




     Column(
          children[
                   Lottie.asset( 
                                  controller: _controller,
                                  'assets/mute.json', 
                                  animate: true,
                                  onLoaded: (composition) {
                                       setState(() { 
                                      _controller.duration = composition.duration;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
],
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool mute = false;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
                                                  // add duration
    _controller =  AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));

  }
```

use animateTo method on controller.

```
InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              mute = !mute;
              log(mute.toString());
              if (mute) {
                _controller.animateTo(0.5);
              } else {
                _controller.animateTo(0);
              }
            },
            child: LottieBuilder.network(
              "https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/animated-icons/icons/no-sound/no-sound.json",
              controller: _controller,
              height: 200,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I have one question. How to change color to white. My app included dark mode

Comment: you will have to add another animation JSON file for dark mode. or maybe try searching different solution.

Comment: One problem- first click not animated but after first click  second, third click nice worked with animation. Help me! @Jay  for this problem

Comment: if the icon is in un-mute state value is 0, and 0.5 for a mute state. so on un-mute click do animate to 0.5. or just 
           
              if (mute) {
                _controller.animateTo(0.5);
              } else {
                _controller.animateTo(0);
              }
mute = !mute; change value after if else.

Comment: Yeah it's worked. Can u send me ur contact pls. My qqqt651@gmail.com